# How to define a constant creator method in Java

Tags: java

How can I define a constant in my class that returns a object? What I'm looking for is something like `BigInteger.ZERO`

Comment: Declare a static variable of that object type in your class.

Comment: `public static final BigInteger ZERO = new BigInteger(new int[0], 0);`

Comment: To be accurate the "constant" member of your class will not "return" anything. Methods return things. Do you want a method that return an immutable variable ?

Comment: Will this create a new instance of the object every time? otherwise, how can I make sure it is immutable?

Answer (score 0):

This is how `BigInteger.ZERO` is defined :

```
public static final BigInteger ZERO = new BigInteger(new int[0], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static final type CONST_NAME = new SomeObject();

    ...
}
```

Then you can do `SomeClass.CONST_NAME`